# I've copied VBA code from a Wise Owl video tutorial to facilitate web scraping the XE Website, but I get a persistent "Type mismatch" error

Tags: vba

As you will probable see from the code below, I have tried a number of ways to get past the `Set HTMLIDS = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("p")`. This code is directly copied from Wise Owl YouTube video "...Part 47.1 - Browsing to Websites..." obviously, with a different Website.
What I am trying to do is get the price of Bitcoin or Ethereum on a daily basis.

```vb
'===================================================================================
'
'   SOURCE - Wise Owl
'
Sub BrowseXESiteWithQueryStringAndHTML()
    Dim XMLPage         As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc         As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLResponse    As String
    Dim HTMLInput1      As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLInput2      As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLID          As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLIDS         As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLButton      As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLButtons     As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection

    Dim URLString   As String
    
    URLString = "https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=XBT&To=USD"
    XMLPage.Open "GET", URLString, False
    XMLPage.send

    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

    Set HTMLIDS = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("p") '<====Type Mismatch occurs on this line
    Set HTMLIDS = HTMLDoc.getElementById("siteHeader") '<====Tried this, this worked,
                                                       '     but this is only 
                                                       '     line 12 of the HTML
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim HTMLIDS As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection`?

Comment: Both lines should fail. The line you indicate worked (via comment) is retrieving a single element not a collection and was possibly meant to be `HTMLID`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
Set HTMLIDS = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("result__BigRate-sc-1bsijpp-1 iGrAod")(0)
```

and if you add the line below after it

```
Debug.Print HTMLIDS.innerText
```

you should see the html-source price in the *Immediate Window*:
[image: Screenshot showing validity of proposed syntax]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already tried that, not that specific Debug, but that Set, and it didn't work. And I just tried it again, and it didn't work again. Still getting Run Time error 13 Type Mismatch. A thought occurred to me, could there be too many ClassName's, and it's getting confused?

Comment: I tried all these, '
'    Set HTMLIDS = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("p")
'    Set HTMLIDS = HTMLDoc.getElementById("siteHeader")
'    Set HTMLIDS = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("result__BigRate-sc-1bsijpp-1 iGrAod")
'    Debug.Print HTMLIDS.innerText
'    Set HTMLInput1 = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("result")
'    Set HTMLInput1 = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("tabindex=")
siteHeader was the only one that worked and that is no good to me.

Comment: @JoeCampanini, I'm a veteran viewer of WiseOwl videos - I've edited my answer to include a screenshot showing that the answer works.

Comment: I am a little surprised this worked given you are assigning an  HTMLParaElement as a collection but it works. You actually end up with an HTMLParaElement though the locals window shows type as HTMLElementCollection/HTMLParaElement. I think I would still prefer more explicit typing but +1 I'd also avoid the class name as it looks dynamic.

Comment: Thank you SpectralInstance, I really, really appreciate the effort you are making to help me, but I'm still getting the same dammed error. Would it be possible if you could send me the exact code you used and let me see if it works on my device. It will probable be some silly typing error I've made, but I'm too fixed on what I've done, that I can't see it. Once again, thank you.

Comment: @JoeCampanini, your 2nd comment showed that you tried the `getElementsByClassName()` syntax, with the _same_ class I used, but **you omitted the `(0)`** from the end of it, you can see the `(0)` at the end, both in the 'copyable' code from my answer, and the 2nd last line of code in my screenshot.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I told you it would be some silly typing error on my behalf. I can honestly say, I've been looking so hard, for so long, I did not see the (0) at the end. I can't believe I missed it. Take care my friend, and have a wonderful rest of the day.